# How can I make the current time update every second?

Tags: ios

I have a label that displays the time; however, the time is not updated. The time is displayed, but it does not count up. The time at which the button was pressed is displayed and that time does not change. Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender
{
[self.videoCamera start];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *currentDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];


for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i--) {
Label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentTime];
Label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentDate];    
   }

}
```

I tried a for loop but that does not update the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: For loops are nasty in an event based system. I'd look for some event you can listen for.

Comment: Look into `NSTimer`.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison What do you mean?

Comment: You got an infinite loop.
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i--) will never stop since 'i' will never be bigger than 10.

Comment: Use NSTimer with intervall = 1 second (1000 ms)

Comment: @AlexWien That worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

UI updates are performed using an event loop that runs on the main thread.  Your for-loop is hogging the main thread and never returns from you start function.  Whatever you set in labelx.text never gets refreshed on screen because the run loop is waiting for your start function to finish.

You should read up on NSTimer to implement this using best practices.

There is also a way to do this using a delayed dispatch:
(sorry that this is in Swift, I don't know objective-C, but I'm sure you'll get the idea)

```
// add this function and call it in your start function
func updateTime()
{
  // update label1 and label2 here
  // also add an exit condition to eventually stop
  let waitTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC )  // one second wait duration
  dispatch_after(waitTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.updateTime() }) // updateTime() calls itself every 1 second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer works but its not very accurate.

When I need accurate timers I use CADisplaylink, especially when working with animations. This reduces visual stutter.

Using the display refresh is accurate and reliable. However you don't want to be doing heavy calculations using this method.

```
- (void)startUpdateLoop {
    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update:)];
    displayLink.frameInterval = 60;
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)update {
    // set you label text here.
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that NSTimer would be so inaccurate that it couldn't attain a one second precision.   Did you measure this ?  Would a user actually notice if the seconds on the clock updated half a second late ?

Comment: Third paragraph in the NSTimer docs. Ultimately it really depends what you're using it for. StopWatch/Metronome I'd avoid NSTimer. 100ms is certainly noticeable. To the person who down voted me, please explain why. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html

Comment: So even according to spec. it's plenty fast enough for the purpose at hand.  100ms may be noticeable in an animation scenario but this isn't applicable here.  NSTimer can refresh the clock 10 times faster than required.  So it does indeed depend on what you're using it for.   It is quite appropriate here, more so than low level approaches such as the one I suggested below or an even lower level one from core animation.